# "possible duplicate of"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, duplicates

When one votes to close a question as being a duplicate, a comment is automatically added of the form

> possible duplicate of Other Question Here

I guess it's good that something appears, but the capitalization and punctuation should really be fixed.

I think the "possible" should be removed as well. If one is voting to close a question on this basis, it makes sense to make a stand and declare that the question is a duplicate. I see no need for weasel words here.

Comment: This bugs me sufficiently that I will edit the automatic comment to read "Possible duplicate of OQH."  (Although I like "possible", since it seems like saying "I think…".)

Comment: @TH.: Can you explain why the comment hasn't been added [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7614/1235)? (And can you explain why noone else has voted to close that one? `;-)`)

Comment: @Hendrik: Because I edited that one. Dunno why no one else voted to close. Probably because there are only 20 of us who can, 5 of whom are moderators who tend not to, and only one nonmoderator (Will) who can see the list of questions that have votes to close.

Comment: @TH.: Huh? There's no trace of an edit of yours. The point about the list of questions with close votes is good one. So I should go and upvote every single answer you've given? `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: Comments don't show edits, do they? (I'm pretty sure they don't, but I've been wrong about how this site works about a billion times.) Speaking of upvotes, I've been wondering for some time now what stops someone from registering a second account, answering two questions which the main account upvotes and then every day the second account upvotes 20 answers given by the main account. And of course, this need not stop at one account. Once all answers have been upvoted, a 3rd account can start the process over again. (I can't help thinking about these sorts of things. It's what I do.)

Comment: @TH. what stops that is that there's a moderator tool "Suspicious vote patterns" where we can spot you doing that and remove all those votes (or something, I don't think that this has been used yet here.  Compared with some SE sites, we're a pretty sedate lot!)

Comment: @TH.: Maybe we've talked at cross-purposes. _Your_ comment has been edited twice. I had been wondering why the "possible duplicate" comment hadn't been added to the question. Now it has been added (after the actual closing, I guess), and it even has capitalization and punctuation (although the question doesn't show it has been edited). I'm even more puzzled!

Comment: @Andrew: Ah, okay. The faq makes it sound like the moderator tools and the access that high rep users get is similar and I never saw anything like that (back when I had access). Not that I _want_ that sort of thing.

Comment: @Hendrik: After using this site for months, I just now noticed that you can see that a comment has been edited! When you first vote to close, a comment gets added in your name that you can edit. That's exactly what I did. I don't know if I edited it twice, or if it got edited again.

Comment: I'm not really satisfied with Jeff's answer. This is just a string in code somewhere. Similar to the double hyphens instead of an em dash issue that this site was ridiculed for a little while back, I think it reflects fairly poorly on our web site about typesetting that we _choose_ not to use basic punctuation correctly.

Comment: @TH.: Ah, finally I understand your post above, it's about an _extra_ comment. _There_ I think the "possible" is good, but I do agree with your other points. (I can't really believe that your comment got edited by anyone else but you.)

Comment: @Hendrik: It's possible that a moderator edited it, they have that power. That said, you're probably right that I did it.

Comment: @TH.: I forgot to say that I'm also not satisfied with the answer. What you'll have to do, I guess, is to prove that it's indeed better to have capitalization (probably not of "Duplicate" as [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7614/1235)) and punctuation although it's not a sentence. Do you know of any good references?

Comment: @Hendrik: I should have put a bit more effort into writing that comment, I suppose. =) I'm afraid I don't know any good references. I think it should become a complete sentence though which would make the point moot.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a system design that has since been redesigned entirely.

Answer (score 2):

If you **make the comment containing the link first**, the system doesn't create an automatic comment for you. Then you can phrase the comment as you wish, which is probably easier than editing.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design; that's not a sentence in the same way the tab headers are not sentences.

Also, Antal, when you edit that comment you are preventing those comment(s) from being auto-deleted in the event the question *is* closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It's almost a sentence. "This question is a possible duplicate of Other Question Here." would be great. Is there a technical reason this couldn't be done? Like Antal, I have edited these comments before.